# I can't seem to split my image and paragraph in CodePen

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, codepen

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <p id="p1" class="box">I am an Art and Computer Science student. I love mixing my art background with web development and design. My goal is to find a job in the web development industry. In my spare time I love playing sports and board games.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img class="pic" src="https://beebom-redkapmedia.netdna-ssl.com/wp-
        content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-
        2016.jpg" alt="filter for now: cat"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am using CodePen and trying to split these two things (the p and the img) using the bootstrap grid and it won't split. The image stays underneath the paragraph.

Comment: Split as in splitting hairs? :-) It will split if the screen (i.e. the inner part) is at least `md` size. Also, adding the `img-fluid` class to the image is a good idea.

Comment: Haha! How do I distinguish the screen size (sm, md, lg)?

Comment: You don't need to distinguish. The browser does that. You just need to make the window big enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably not including the link to bootstrap. Here I am linking the bootstrap cdn within the header tags.

```
<html>  
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <p id="p1" class="box">I am an Art and Computer Science student. I love 
            mixing my art background with web development and design. My goal is to 
            find a job in the web development industry. In my spare time I love 
            playing sports and board games.</p></div> 

            <div class="col-md-6">
            <img class="pic" src="https://beebom-redkapmedia.netdna-ssl.com/wp-
            content/uploads/2016/01/Reverse-Image-Search-Engines-Apps-And-Its-Uses-
            2016.jpg" alt="filter for now: cat"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this might be it.. it messed with my display a bit, but I think if I just fix what I have so far, I can use bootstrap correctly. THANK YOU